Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange points system exploit discovered
There are a number of users who are gaining points by either creating posts and having their friends upvote, or else they are copying another (often accepted) answer, and then rephrasing it.  Although it is exactly the same, it still means that some users upvote without crediting the original answer.

Maybe I am imagining it, but I've followed a few users' posts, and it
looks like this:

Find a post with an already accepted answered

Add a new answer, and simply say you are "emphasising" the other
answer.

Google a trivial or irrelevant fact about the answer (or put the
answer through AI to rephrase it)

Post, and watch people upvote your answer, or get people you know to upvote.


Why is there nothing in place to flag this? Shouldn't this be abuse of the terms of service?

"Why is there nothing in place to flag this?" Flag -> In need of moderator attention. If you don't see that option in the dialog, you should probably report it as a bug.

There is also the Flag -> Plagiarized content on SO.

I meant more along the detection route - like anti-cheat measures where AI looks for patterns (same IP address posting under different accounts, with use of the same language)

"I meant more along the detection route - like anti-cheat measures where AI looks for patterns", The community (mods and curators) has been asking SE to improve the internal search engine for more than ten years, among other things, and there are no response. I don't think SE is willing to spend a truckload of money a month training a high end stochastic anti-cheat/fraud system, because in addition to being expensive don't always work as intended. "same IP address posting under different accounts" is allowed as long as the accounts do not interact with each other.

There is a way to flag this: flag as “In need of moderator intervention”, describe the issue, and the moderators will take care of it.
There are some automatic systems in place to detect voting fraud. Examples include a single user upvoting/downvoting the posts of another user a large number of times will be automatically reversed. These systems, however, aren’t perfect, and as stated above, if you see something like that, please flag for moderator intervention.

What happens - do I get feedback on a reported issue?  I meant like AI pattern matching otherwise anyone can do it.

When the flag is reviewed, it will (usually) be marked helpful or declined

For what it's worth, @csharp, you can review your personal flag history for Stack Overflow on this page, including the response from moderators (once they've been reviewed). If you disagree with moderators' assessment, you could reflag and provide additional evidence/rationale refuting the decline (such flags will be reviewed by a different mod than the one who handled the first one), or you could open a [support] question on Meta Stack Overflow (which will get more eyes, including from regular community members).
